# Styling graphs in Memgraph Lab

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

When I generate graph using Memgraph Lab I get something that looks like this:

[image: Final graph]

I would like to change the styling of nodes and relationships. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph Lab uses [Graph Style Script language](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab/graph-style-script-language) for styling. You can use `EdgeStyle` directive properties and `NodeStyle` directive properties to style your graph.

For example, you can change the color and size of nodes with the following code:

```
@NodeStyle {
  size: 35
  border-width: 5
  border-color: #ffffff
  shadow-color: #333333
  shadow-size: 20
}
```

With the following code you will change the visual representation of relationships:

```
@EdgeStyle {
  width: 1
  label: Type(edge)
  arrow-size: 0
  color: #6AA84F
}
```